# Small issues when creating a function that checks if a code is valid

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a rev question which asks to check if a code is valid or not. A code is valid if it is made up of 1 letter in the `code_letters` list, and digit(s) that are within a certain range.

```py
code_letters = ["S", "B", "N", "T", "P"]
min_for_each_letter = [1, 3, 4, 0, 3] #inclusive
max_for_each_letter = [7, 9, 6, 7, 5] #inclusive
```

Parameters:

- `code_letters` is the list of code letters which are valid for the first letter of the code string
- `min_for_each_letter` is a list which contains the minimum possible number (inclusive) for each digit following that letter
- `max_for_each_letter` is a list which contains the maximum possible number (inclusive) for each digit following that letter

e.g. If code contains "S" its digit(s) can only be between 1 and 7, inclusive, or if code contains "N" its digit(s) can only be between 4 and 6 inclusive.
 There has to be only 1 letter and at least 1 digit, if there are multiple digits they all have to be within the range of the letter to be valid, and invalid otherwise

Here is the code I have written, so far:

```py
def is_a_valid_code(code):
    code_letters = ["S", "B", "N", "T", "P"]
    min_for_each_letter = [1, 3, 4, 0, 3] #inclusive
    max_for_each_letter = [7, 9, 6, 7, 5] #inclusive
      
    if code[0] not in code_letters:
        return False
    else:
        x = code_letters.index(code[0])
    
    for ele in code[1:]:
        if ele != " ":
            if ele.isdigit() == False or int(ele) < min_for_each_letter[x] or int(ele) > max_for_each_letter[x]:
                return False
                    
    if not False:
        return True
```

It works for test cases such as:

```py
is_a_valid_code('B747346')
is_a_valid_codeN('N  444  454')
is_a_valid_codeT('T 400 4854')
is_a_valid_codeS('S  444S454')
```

But fails for cases like these:

```py
is_a_valid_code('P  ') # Should return False, not True
```

Is there a way to account for such cases? I think there is a simple fix but .isalpha() doesn't consider whitespace

Comment: @GoodDeeds Sorry it was a mistake from a previous attempt, it should be code_letters.index(code[0])

Comment: It is not clearly specified why your test case should return false. Do you need to ensure that there is at least one digit?

Comment: @GoodDeeds There has to be only 1 letter and at 1 digit, if there are multiple digits they all have to be within the range of the letter

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
def is_a_valid_code(code):
    code_letters = ["S", "B", "N", "T", "P"]
    min_for_each_letter = [1, 3, 4, 0, 3] #inclusive
    max_for_each_letter = [7, 9, 6, 7, 5] #inclusive
      
    if code[0] not in code_letters:
        return False
    else:
        x = code_letters.index(code[0])
    
    is_non_whitespace_found = False
    for ele in code[1:]:
        if ele != " ":
            is_non_whitespace_found = True
            if ele.isdigit() == False or int(ele) < min_for_each_letter[x] or int(ele) > max_for_each_letter[x]:
                return False
    if not is_non_whitespace_found:
        return False
    else:           
        return True

print(is_a_valid_code('B747346'))
print(is_a_valid_code('N  444  454'))
print(is_a_valid_code('T 400 4854'))
print(is_a_valid_code('S  444S454'))
print(is_a_valid_code('P  '))
```

result:

```
True
True
False
False
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative way of looking at this problem, you could construct a regex which matches your requirements and test that against each input code.

For each code letter we make a regex which looks something like

```regex
^S(?:\s*[1-7])+\s*$
```

which requires the code to be an `S` followed by at least one digit in the range 1 to 7, with some number of spaces allowed as well. We can then put all those code parts into an overall regex to test against the input values.

For example:

```py
import re

code_letters = ["S", "B", "N", "T", "P"]
min_for_each_letter = [1, 3, 4, 0, 3] #inclusive
max_for_each_letter = [7, 9, 6, 7, 5] #inclusive

regex = re.compile('(?:' + '|'.join(f'{l}(?:\s*[{n}-{x}])+\s*' for l, n, x in zip(code_letters, min_for_each_letter, max_for_each_letter)) + ')$')

def is_a_valid_code(code):
    return regex.match(code) is not None

print(is_a_valid_code('B747346'))
print(is_a_valid_code('N  444  454'))
print(is_a_valid_code('T 400 4854 '))
print(is_a_valid_code('S  444S454'))
print(is_a_valid_code('T 400 4354 '))
print(is_a_valid_code('S  7654 321 '))
print(is_a_valid_code('P    '))
```

Output:

```py
True
True
False
False
True
True
False
```

Comment: We will only be covering regex later on in the semester so this is quite foreign to me, hopefully I can revisit this later on and understand it better, but thanks!

Comment: @didleyr6s no worries - I figured you were more concerned with fixing your code (which it seems you have an answer for) but just wanted to throw out an alternate approach to the problem. When you do look at regex, come back and have another look and if you have any questions about how it works, just ping me.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal change to posted code.

**Code**

```
def is_a_valid_code(code):
    code_letters = ["S", "B", "N", "T", "P"]
    min_for_each_letter = [1, 3, 4, 0, 3] #inclusive
    max_for_each_letter = [7, 9, 6, 7, 5] #inclusive
      
    if code[0] not in code_letters:
        return False
    
    x = code_letters.index(code[0])
        
    found_digit = False      # Flag to check we had at least one valid digit
    for ele in code[1:]:
        if ele != " ":
            if ele.isdigit() and min_for_each_letter[x] <= int(ele) <=  max_for_each_letter[x]:
                found_digit = True  # found a digit in proper range
            else:
                return False   # Was not a digit, or in incorrect range
     
    return found_digit         # result depends on us finding at least one digit
```

**Tests**

```
# Test Cases
for code in ['B747346', 'N  444  454', 'T 400 4854', 'S  444S454', 'P  ']:
    print(f"{code:<15} code validity is {is_a_valid_code(code)}")
```

**Output**

```
B747346         code validity is True
N  444  454     code validity is True
T 400 4854      code validity is False
S  444S454      code validity is False
P               code validity is False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_a_valid_code(code):
    code_letters = ["S", "B", "N", "T", "P"]
    min_for_each_letter = [1, 3, 4, 0, 3] #inclusive
    max_for_each_letter = [7, 9, 6, 7, 5] #inclusive
      
    if code[0] not in code_letters:
        return False
    else:
        x = code_letters.index(code[0])

    icount=0
    
    for ele in code[1:]:

        if ele != " ":
            if ele.isdigit() == False or int(ele) < min_for_each_letter[x] or int(ele) > max_for_each_letter[x]:
                return False
        else:
            icount+=1

    if icount == len(code)-1:
        return False
                    
    if not False:
        return True


is_a_valid_code('P  ') # Returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last sample provided, `'P  '` (which fails), the `if` statement nested in the `for` loop will check all the characters except for `P`. `code[1:]` in this case will be `"  "` (two spaces), so the `if` condition evaluates to `False`, so nothing is checked against the code criteria.

(Also, in the last line of your function, `not False` will *always* evaluated to `True`, so the `if` statement itself is redundant; instead just `return True` would be better.)

I think the best approach would be to create a list containing the validity of each character following the first character (`code[1:]`), then returning whether *all* the elements of the list are `True` and that the list is not empty (so that cases such as `'P  '` do not pass).

---

```py
def is_valid(code):
    code_letters = ["S", "B", "N", "T", "P"]
    letter_minimum = [1, 3, 4, 0, 3]
    letter_maximum = [7, 9, 6, 7, 5]
    if code[0] not in code_letters:
        return False
    index = code_letters.index(code[0])
    num_range = (letter_minimum[index], letter_maximum[index])
    validity = []
    for i in code[1:]:
        if i == " ":
            continue
        try:
            i = int(i)
            if not (num_range[0] <= i <= num_range[1]):
                validity.append(False)
        except ValueError:
            validity.append(False)
        validity.append(True)
    return bool(all(validity) and validity)
```

---

With the sample codes provided, a few test runs:

```py
>>> is_valid('B747346')
True
>>> is_valid('N  444  454')
True
>>> is_valid('T 400 4854')    # Fails because 8 is out of the range [0, 7].
False
>>> is_valid('S  444S454')    # Fails because 'S' is not a number
False
>>> is_valid('P  ')    # Fails because no numbers exist
False
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Wouldn't have caught them otherwise